# flask mysqldb call a related table

Tags: python, mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

**Flask-mysqldb**

Is there a way to call the related table without making a new query? if it's stored within the teacher object or something.

So I have the id under 'teacher' and they have a relation in MySQL.

```
{% for class1 in classes %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{class1.name}}</td>
          <td>{{class1.code}}</td>
          <td>{{class1.teacher}}</td>
```

Outputs: 'Classname', 'Classcode', 2

Something like

```
<td>{{class1.teacher.name}}</td>
```